# Coloring SVG content url with css

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a button set up like this:

```
<button class="buttonclass"><i class="iconclass plus-icon"></i></button>
```

My css classes look like this:

```
.buttonclass {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #1DBE60
}

.iconclass {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 7.5px;
}

.buttonclass .iconclass {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.plus-icon {
  content: url(http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/mfg-labs/svg/plus.svg);
}
```

How can I change the color of the 'plus-icon' with css if it is an SVG? I have tried adding fill classes to the svg, color classes, background-classes, etc.

Here is a plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6fLYQlpFmDdf7aWenBtp?p=preview

Comment: That is not possible when using SVG as a background image. https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Typically you would use an icon font for this rather than an svg.

Comment: @CBroe What would be the best approach to using an svg as an icon then? Do I HAVE to use inline svg? Is there any way I can use my current set up by using a class ?

Comment: @BrianGlaz I have my own set of custom icons that I am using as svg's... What would be a better approach to using them like this, then?

Comment: This should be helpful: http://rafaltomal.com/how-to-create-and-use-your-own-icon-fonts/

Comment: You could have 2 plus icons, one of each colour and swap between them. Or you could load your SVG via the object tag and then put the CSS in the SVG file itself.

Comment: Just use the ``<use>`` tag which is specififcally made for cases like this. You make one svg with all the icons combined, each icon in a ``<symbol>`` element and then you can use those icons everywhere with the  ``<use>`` tag.

Answer (score 5):

If you're happy to add one extra class (for the color of the plus icon) then here's a CSS-only solution using the `currentColor` CSS variable:

```css
.buttonclass {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #1DBE60
}

.iconclass {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 7.5px;
}

.buttonclass .iconclass {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.plus-icon {
background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><rect x="0" y="0" width="8" height="8" fill="rgb(29,190,96)" /><rect x="0" y="12" width="8" height="8" fill="rgb(29,190,96)" /><rect x="12" y="0" width="8" height="8" fill="rgb(29,190,96)" /><rect x="12" y="12" width="8" height="8" fill="rgb(29,190,96)" /></svg>');
background-color: currentColor;
border: 1px solid rgb(29,190,96);
border-radius: 15px;
}

.white {
color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

.yellow {
color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

.green {
color: rgb(0,255,0);
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonclass"><i class="iconclass plus-icon white"></i></button>
<button class="buttonclass"><i class="iconclass plus-icon yellow"></i></button>
<button class="buttonclass"><i class="iconclass plus-icon green"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the svg inline but consider using the `<use>` element instead so you can use an icon multiple time by referencing it:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here looking for a way to color a svg icon. The most voted answer didn't helped me so after some googling i came across to this interesting [codepen](https://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images).

Long story short i colored my svg icon using this css:

```
.plus-icon {
    -webkit-mask: url('../images/plus.svg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    mask: url('../images/plus.svg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    -webkit-mask-size: cover;
    mask-size: cover;
}

.white {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

**Update:**

Not working with IE.